# Unchecked casting complain by FindBugs

Tags: java, findbugs

Consider the following code :

```
 public void broadcast(FacesEvent event)
    throws AbortProcessingException {

    if(!(event instanceof WrapperEvent)) {
      super.broadcast(event);
      return;
    }

    // Sets up the correct context and fire our wrapped event.
    GridWrapperEvent revent = (GridWrapperEvent)event; // FindBugs is complaining here 
    int oldRowIndex = getRowIndex();
    int oldColumnIndex = getColumnIndex();
    boolean oldClientIdRewritting = clientIdRewritting;
    setClientIdRewritting(revent.isClientIdRewritting());

    setActiveCell(revent.getRowIndex(), revent.getColumnIndex());

    FacesEvent rowEvent = revent.getFacesEvent();
    rowEvent.getComponent().broadcast(rowEvent);
    setActiveCell(oldRowIndex, oldColumnIndex);
    setClientIdRewritting(oldClientIdRewritting);
  }
```

[FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) is complaining about the commented line. Is there anything that I can do about it? This is what FindBugs says:

> **Unchecked/unconfirmed cast** 
>      This cast is unchecked, and not all
>   instances of the type casted from can be cast to the type it is being
>   cast to. Ensure that your program logic ensures that this cast will
>   not fail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you *know* that `event` will always be a `GridWrapperEvent`, you can ignore the warning. Otherwise you can wrap the cast (and the logic depending on it) inside a check like

```
if (event instanceof GridWrapperEvent) {
  // ...
}
```

In fact you're already doing this, but for the (I assume) more generic `WrapperEvent` class. Perhaps you could adapt that check instead of adding a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `spotbugs-exclude.xml` to skip false positive warnings

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FindBugsFilter>
    <Match>
        <!-- Unchecked cast warning -->
        <Bug pattern="BC_UNCONFIRMED_CAST"/>
        <Class name="com.example.MyClass"/> <!-- Specify your class name -->
        <Method name="someMethod"/> <!-- Specify your method name -->
    </Match>
</FindBugsFilter>
```